# Display markup only after JavaScript has executed

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am working on a jQuery Mobile App, and it is all front end, there is no back end server code at all.

So in order to handle a `<form method="get">...</form>` I have some jQuery that parses the URL to get the Query String parameters.

My jQuery code on the form target page is as follows:

```
// Get Query String Values
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();



var searchedProduct = urlParams['name'];
var productTitle = $('.product-title');
var productImage = $('.product-image img');

//start ajax request
$.ajax({
    url: "data/results.json",
    //force to handle it as text
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {

        //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
        //and pass downloaded data
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        //now json variable contains data in json format
        //let's display a few items
        $.each(json.products, function(i, item) {

            if(item.name.toLowerCase() === searchedProduct.toLowerCase())
            {
                productTitle.html(item.name);
                productImage.attr('src', item.image);
                productImage.attr('alt', item.name);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My intial page where the form is submitted is the following:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <form action="results.html" method="get" id="product-search-form">
        <p>Let us save you some money, begin your searh below</p>

        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Type your search query" data-clear-btn="true" />
        <input type="submit" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-theme="a" class="search-btn" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

A parameter `name=cocacola` comes in via the form (i.e. I type in cocacola and submit the form), but when the page loads, I don't see the word `CocaCola` and the image of `CocaCola` via the JSON file, I have to refresh the page, then they show!

My guess is because the page content below:

```
<div data-role="content">

    <h2 class="product-title"></h2>

    <div class="product-image">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>

    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="acura.html">eBuyer (&pound;300)</a></li>
        <li><a href="audi.html">Amazon (&pound;320)</a></li>
        <li><a href="bmw.html">Overclockers (&pound;323)</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

loads before the jQuery/JavaScript has done its magic. How can I get this to work without me refreshing the page to see the expected result?

Comment: When/how do you run the code above?

Comment: So you load an external page result.html and run the code on popstate event. This code is placed in index.html (form page) or result.html? if result.html, is it in head? If not, place inside page div.

Comment: I'm not sure what a `popstate event` is, but yes I am submitting my form to `result.html` and it is on there that I process the JSON.

Comment: Have tried adding the code of json processing inside result.html page div?

Comment: just did, same thing happens :( I have to refresh the page in order for it to show.

Comment: Ok, maybe you should disable Ajax when moving to _results.html_. Add `data-ajax="false"` attribute to _form_.

Comment: Can you reply with that as an answer please. That fixed it :D

Comment: Good news :) I'd recommend you post an answer since you know the problem better than me. I dislike adding short answers, I hope you understand me ;)